# I cannot connect to MySQL server database from my android phone while I can from android studio emulator

Tags: android, sql-server

I'm working on android login app with online SQL server database that I have to access it from any platform. I opened the 1433 port and and connect with my ip address and did all the configuration in SQL server still cannot connect from my phone while I can connect from the android studio easily.

Please help me, perhaps I'm missing little things.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    ConnectionClass connectionClass;
    EditText edtuserid,edtpass;
    Button btnlogin;
    ProgressBar pbbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
        edtuserid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtuserid);
        edtpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpass);
        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        pbbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
        pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DoLogin doLogin = new DoLogin();
                doLogin.execute("");

            }
        });

    }

    public class DoLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        String z = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;


        String userid = edtuserid.getText().toString();
        String password = edtpass.getText().toString();


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
            pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,r,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(isSuccess) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, attendance.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            if(userid.trim().equals("")|| password.trim().equals(""))
                z = "Please enter User Id and Password";
            else
            {
                try {
                    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                    if (con == null) {
                        z = "Error in connection with The server";
                    } else {
                        String query = "select * from tablename where id='" + userid + "' and Password='" + password + "'";
                        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                        if(rs.next())
                        {

                            z = "Login successfull ";
                            isSuccess=true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            z = "Invalid Credentials";
                            isSuccess = false;
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    isSuccess = false;
                    z = "Exceptions";
                }
            }
            return z;
        }
    }
}
```

**ConnectionClass.java**

```
public class ConnectionClass {
    String ip = "192.168.....etc";
    String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String db = "dbname";
    String un = "sql server login username";
    String password = "*****";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        try {

            Class.forName(classs);
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                    + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                    + password + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to access an online DB? It looks like it is local based on your ip (192.168...). Make sure you are on the same Wifi and check for your device IP to connect to it. It will work on Emulator since it has the same IP as your computer if that is the case.

Comment: as @Gil said your phone cant access your DB because its in the local server

Comment: @Gil so how do connect to the db or how make it online ... do i need i hosting website for my db??? cause i want to reach it from vb.net too

Comment: @user10146728, Unfortunately this is way beyond my client's skill set. But you do need a hosting service to make it online and then get the path to it after uploading it to hosting.

Comment: @user10146728 you could try local tunnel like ngrok.

Comment: @Gil ok no problem thank u

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil ngrok ????

Comment: Yes sir. https://ngrok.com/ it'll tunnel your local machine and give a Public URLs for you to access.

Comment: thanks @MadhanVaradhodiyil looks cool i will google it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DB can be local, but you must configure your network so it can be reach from the outside.

**First**
If you want to have the DB at your local server, you must ensure to have a fixed IP from you ISP or use other means to ensure that you IP is always reachable even when the IP change (no-ip and such can do this for you).

**Second**
You must do the Port forward from the router to you DB Server, so when it gets a connection it will redirect to you DB Server.

My advice is to have it in a hosting service

Comment: my idea from the beginning is to put in hosting server put some people told me the sqlserver is working as webservices and u dont need a hosting ..etc

Comment: Thanks ill put it in hosting site